# my jquery function is executed a lot of time instead of one

Tags: jquery, mouseover, opacity, mouseout

when I'm passing my mouse over .test I want .hide to show and when I'm passing my mouse out .test I want .hide to hide

Unfortunatly it shows and it hides more than once.

My code is:

```
.hide{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: "old-ie-staff";
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function () {
    $(this).find('.hide').animate({opacity: 1},300);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').animate({opacity: 0},300);
});
```

here a Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/2bnZW/

Comment: You should look at adding a [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before your `.animate()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple animation sequences will be queued when performing `mouseover` or `mouseout` on the element. jQuery provides a way to stop these animations and remove them from the animation queue.

Adding [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before `.animate()` will

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements

The `true` parameter will also remove any already queued animations - see [Prevent Animation Queue Buildup](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear queued animation;

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function () {
    $(this).find('.hide').stop(true).animate({opacity: 1},300);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').stop(true).animate({opacity: 0},300);
})
```